# How to make a property of a property

Tags: objective-c

I'm not quite sure how to word this question, so I'll show examples. I want to make a property for a property. I am currently using a property from a different class:

```
player = [[Player alloc] init];
player.name = @"PlayerName";
```

These properties are defined in the Player class, and Player.h is imported.

I want to have a 'sub-property' for .name, so it will look like player.name.newProperty. An example of this is for UILabel:

```
labelName = [[UILabel alloc] init];
self.labelName.text = @"String"; // .text being the 'sub-property'
```

Comment: "Sub-properties" are not a concept in any language I'm aware of.  What you're looking at is the shortened and sugared form of two getters.  The first is a getter for a UILabel instance owned by self, the second is the getter for the Label's text.  To make "sub-properties", make a subclass of the object, add a benign getter or some properties, then, in turn, make that object a member of self.

Answer (score 1):

Right now, `player.name` is an `NSString`

If instead of an `NSString`, you make it a custom class, with it's own properties, you will be able to access them as "sub-properties"

```
player.name = [[MyCustomObject alloc] init];
player.name.subProperty = @"value";
```

Keep in mind, you will need to create the appropriate .m and .h files for MyCustomObject and define its properties.

Comment: I tried player.name = [[MyCustomObject alloc] init] but it won't work, please could you further explain how I should go about doing this? I made the MyCustomObject class and gave it properties, it should work like you said and look like player.name.property but I get an error.

Comment: What error are you getting?  Did you said the `name` property to be of the type `MyCustomObject`?

Comment: Actually I'm not quite sure how to do that, could you explain please?

Comment: First, I'd like to know what error you are getting so I can see if that's really the problem.